# laravel Auth::attempt() always returning false

Tags: laravel

I'm making a simple user authentication with laravel passport, I made an `AuthController` where I put `login` and `register` functions, whenever I try to login with the right email and password I get

> {"message":"invalid user"}

its like the `attempt()` method always returning false, I am using laravel 8.

here is **AuthController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use http\Env\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        if(Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
            $user=Auth::user();
            return $user;
        }
        return response([
            'message'=> 'invalid user'
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

**user model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'password',
        'phone',
        'skype',
        'birthdate',
        'address',
        'postalcode',
        'city',
        'country',
        'status',
        'image',
        'description',
        'geo_lat',
        'geo_lng'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;


class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `Auth::attempt()` this is used for session auth what your using ? check your config

Comment: @aib.how you create user .post that code as well.may be encrypted password is wrong one

Comment: @KamleshPaul I saw many tutorials where they used Auth::attempt() with passport authentication this way, what do you suggest that I have to do/change?

Comment: @JohnLobo I created a user record manually in the database, if that what you meant

Comment: for passport use normal where condition to find then if you user exits then generate token  `driver=>passport` you cannot use `Auth::attempt()` function

Comment: @AIB.you cant create manually without encrypting using bcrypt.it wotn work if you encrypt using md5

Comment: How is the user password stored in your database? Is it hashed?

Comment: @pr1nc3 no its not

Comment: Then this is your problem. You must store users with their password hashed not as plain text. Please paste also the register function you are using or the seeder for users.

Comment: @pr1nc3 how can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you import users? Edit your question with the register function OR the seeders. The problem is not in your login function but in your register.

Comment: I still dont have a register or edit functions thats why I am creating users manually to test the login function

Comment: What does dd($request->only('email', 'password')); result in?

Comment: @mrhn                                                                                                                    
    array:2 [
  "email" => "test@gmail.com"
  "password" => "123456"
]

Comment: you can not create users manually, if you dont have a register then use seeders but the password must be stored hashed in your database not as plain text.

Comment: @mrhn right, I made a register function the password inside it is hashed and only then it worked, thank you